# 429 Response with Google Bard

Tags: python, google-api

I am running through some data using the Google Bard API using a for loop that pushes a different sentence through for a total of 120 times.  I initially inserted a random time lag after each point (1 to 10 seconds, randomly chosen) in the for-loop so that it’s hopefully not getting blocked by Google. However, I ran into a timeout and therefore removed the time lag.  Now, I’m getting a 429 response.

My questions are:

- When this happens, is there any way in my code that I can save what’s already been run? So that if there’s an error, my list of Bard responses (what’s there so far) can be saved?
- Does anyone know the limit per second/hour for Bard?  I looked, but I don’t see any documentation…mostly probably because they haven’t created their own API. But shouldn’t their site still indicate what will give a 429?  My error only raises an Exception indicating a 429 response, but no other details.

To answer some of my own questions:

- 1 to 5 seconds time lag actually was sufficient in giving me most of my data before Google Bard knocks me off
- to save data thus far, I should write line by line.

It’s still unclear if there are other packages (celery??) or chunking methods that I should use in this type of situation to be more efficient at pulling down data from an API

Comment: Edit your question and include your code please

Comment: I don’t think my code is necessary here. I’m asking a question about general pointers to avoid 429 errors and specifics about Bard.

Comment: Well it would help to know which API you are using I think there are three that may be considered a bard api.  But none of them are called bard api.  So either give me some code or a link to the docs

Comment: It’s actually called bardapi.  Works really well, except it times out after about 38 responses.  https://pypi.org/project/bardapi/

Comment: Well there's your problem don't use some third party thing use the Palm api or vertex ai

Comment: So you think it’s the package and not Google Bard itself that’s throttling?

Comment: Well I just scanned the code but I think they are just sending stuff directly to bard which is probably against the tos and if not will definitely result in throttling.  Use the true API we are given.

Comment: There’s not an official Google Bard API, per their website. Which official API were you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked in a comment what the official bard api is. You should check out [MakerSuite](https://makersuite.google.com/) and [palm api](https://developers.generativeai.google/tutorials).

MakerSuite is used for Prompt Prototype with generative AI. It lets you create your prompt then it shows you the code you need to use Palm API.

A python example would be

At the command line, only need to run once to install the package via pip:

> $ pip install google-generativeai

```
import google.generativeai as genai

genai.configure(api_key="YOUR API KEY")

defaults = {
  'model': 'models/text-bison-001',
  'temperature': 0.7,
  'candidate_count': 1,
  'top_k': 40,
  'top_p': 0.95,
  'max_output_tokens': 1024,
  'stop_sequences': [],
  'safety_settings': [{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_DEROGATORY","threshold":"BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE"},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_TOXICITY","threshold":"BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE"},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_VIOLENCE","threshold":"BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE"},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUAL","threshold":"BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE"},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_MEDICAL","threshold":"BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE"},{"category":"HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS","threshold":"BLOCK_MEDIUM_AND_ABOVE"}],
}

subject = 'an adventure in an underwater castle'

prompt = f"""Write a poem about {subject}

"""

response = genai.generate_text(
  **defaults,
  prompt=prompt
)

print(response.result)
```

At the time of writing palm api is still free to Use.  Palm api uses the text-bison-001 model which is the same model used by Bard currently.   I have only been hit by flooding errors once with palm but i was arguably spamming it trying to get it to sentiment categorise a lot of data ASAP. There was really no reason for the ASAP so i just slowed it down a bit :)